# Keras: Gradient Ascent using K.gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to train a Keras model to maximize its loss function. Since the build-in Optimizers opt for minimizing the loss, I was wondering if there is a possibility to perform gradient ascent using Keras.

I tried using a negative loss function but was not successful doing this.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Current attempt:**

```
loss = -K.log(other_parameter_input)

grad = K.gradients(loss, self.model.trainable_weights)
self.get_gradients = K.function(inputs=[self.price_vector_input, 
                                  self.prev_weight_input, self.cash_bias_input, mu, y,
                                  self.model.output], outputs=grad)

updates = [self.learning_rate * g for g in grads]

modelWeights = self.model.get_weights()
updateWeights = [np.add(wT, uT) for (wT, uT) in zip(modelWeights, updates)]
self.model.set_weights(updateWeights)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the multiplicative inverse, so something like `loss = 1 / -K.log(other_parameters)` and suddenly it's a minimization problem again...
Don't be the guy who maximizes LOSS.